# For all links, add css to switch color of link based off Post Type using JS or PHP - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm not sure what route to start down or what would be the appropriate way to do what I'm trying to accomplish here. Whether it's possible to do in PHP, or how to do it in JS, any help is greatly appreciated.

For each link found on a page, *(possibly found within widgets,theme's template pages, forums, etc.)*, how do I search and find out the post_type and then append a specific link color for that particular type?

---

So for example:

**For a list of recent posts in a sidebar widget** 

(here is the best way I can describe the code intentions):

```
For each post_type, dynamically set the following
'post'= color:black, 
'project' = color:dark blue,  
'topics' = color:dark green, 
and so on.
```

Additionally, if there is a link to another post anywhere else in the site, such as in another post's body content or even a forum topic, I need to append a class to that link. Then my CSS can be something along the lines of

```
.forum-post-link{color: #006400;}
.project-post-link{color: #00008B;}
.standard-post-link{color:#000;}
```

Comment: not hard with jQuery to parse the `href` of the `<a>` tag if there are distinctions within them to tell which type it is. I don't use WP much to know

Comment: That's what I sort of had in mind but wasn't sure if there was a more efficient way or if it was better practice to use PHP.    So if my links were structured like this:   `http://myurl/project/project-123` `http://myurl/forums/topic/thread-123` `http://myurl/post-123`.. What's the best method to parse all these links, append a class to the `<a>` tag, and if possible, can we get the border-color to do the same  for pictures that are wrapped in`<a>` tags + `/post_type/` in their url?  Also, I guess I'll just leave out post's because I won't be able to separate them from static pages. Thanks!

Comment: would be same parsing principles in php or javascript. A little easier in javascript because you can treat the tag as an object. If done in php though the css takes effect as page loads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that should work off the shelf. You may need to adjust the selector a bit to avoid main site navigation links.

An anchor `<a>` with an `href` automatically has numerous properties such as `hostname` , `pathname` , `origin` etc that relate to various parts of the url. Following uses these properties to isolate links that are external ( not same domain ) and also find the home page links.

It should be fairly easy to adapt to live site based on comments within as well as extend for more than the 3 main routes mentioned in question.

```
/* set according to site domain */
var siteHost = "myurl.com";

var linkClasses = {
    /* adjust string values as classes to suit css rules, keys match term to look for in url */
    post: 'post',
    forum: 'forum',
    project: 'project'
}

$('a').each(function () {

    var host = this.hostname; /* returns domain.com */
    if (host !== siteHost) {
        return; /* not a local link, quit here */
    }
    var newClass = '';
    var path = this.pathname; /* returns eveything after http://myurl.com  */

    if (path && path !== '/') {
        /* we only want to look at first part of path*/
        var mainPath = path.split('/')[1];
        /* now check all the various terms in linkClasses object */ 
        $.each(linkClasses, function (key, value) {
            if (mainPath.indexOf(key) > -1) {
                newClass = linkClasses[key];
            }
        });

        $(this).addClass(newClass);
    } else {
        /* is home page link */
        $(this).addClass('home'); /* to test home page link finding ability */
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hLTfB/2)**</kbd>

Comment: Perfect.. I've altered you're original example to also style the background of any of the same post_type img's wrapped in the '<a>' tag. So now what should I do to exclude the navigation links? Is there a way to check the existing class for the **parent element** of the link this finds?   Here is my thought process of how it "could" work if the code language was corrected `if $(this).parent('li').TheParentsClass('main-nav') then do nothing else run the code to add the class`

Comment: I'm guessing most of these links live inside a main content container. If there is a common class or ID that shows on every page could look within there perhaps...something like `$('.wp_content a')...`

Comment: Yes you're correct. The Nav Menu's I have don't have a class added to the `<a>` element but rather to the parent `<li>` element of sub-menu or main-menu

Comment: can also use `not()` ...something like  `$('a').not('.mainNavClass a').each(..`

Comment: Thank you for the help.. Got it all sorted out now.. Here is the final product with the additional changes and some styling up for demonstration. [Final Results Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8p6Vg/1/)